# Java on-the-fly string replacement

Tags: java, string, replace

I've seen something like this in code

```
somestring = "Today is {0}, tomorrow is {1}";
```

I know that it'll put values into the string from another variable, but how do I do it?

**Update**: As there is several ways to achieve this effect, which way is the most effecient?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you looked at the [MessageFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html) documentation ?

e.g. (an example)

```
 Object[] arguments = {
     new Integer(7),
     new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()),
     "a disturbance in the Force"
 };

 String result = MessageFormat.format(
     "At {1,time} on {1,date}, there was {2} on planet {0,number,integer}.",
     arguments);

 output: At 12:30 PM on Jul 3, 2053, there was a disturbance
           in the Force on planet 7.
```

With respect to your question re. efficiency, I would only worry about this if you encounter performance issues and they relate to this. I would expect the above to be reasonably efficient - especially given there'll likely be some output (to std. out or similar?) involved, which I'd expect to be a bigger bottleneck.

Answer (score 5):

```
// Assuming variables today and tomorrow are strings.
somestring = String.format("Today is %s, tomorrow is %s", today, tomorrow);
```

Comment: Will this work if I get that first string from a .properties file?

Comment: It doesn't matter where the first string is from, just as long as its a String.  Also, if you pass an Object, I believe it will just call `toString()` for that object.

Answer (score 0):

You could use java.text.MessageFormat class

Answer (score 0):

I think specifically your example is using, java.text.MessageFormat.